# How to rebuild an entirely static website, without changing URLs?

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect, static, rebuild

I have a website that I was asked to "redesign".

The site itself was built and still maintained by FrontPage, so there are hundreds (hopefully not more) of HTML pages.

My main limitation is that I can't change any of the URLs because they have been there for over 10 years and have a lot of SEO value.

I want to rebuild the site in a smart way (CSS classes, dynamic pages, etc.) but also give the owner the ability to change content as he needs.

I was thinking of using WordPress, however I don't have experience with it and I'm not sure what it's limitations are.

My other issue, is that I need server side languages in order to enable this kind of site, but I don't know how to do that without changing the URLs.

And after I deal with all that, is there any way around manually handling every single page?

Any suggestions, or pushing in a certain direction are all welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feel free to provide new, meaningful, URLs but make 100% sure that you configure correct 301 redirects from all old URLs to the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may change the *permalinks* from your WordPress admin section once you've written the `.htaccess` file. The old links of the static pages can then be redirect to new pages and links using 301 redirects which won't negatively affect the existing PageRank and SEO; see [How to redirect a webpage](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php)